# Error about permission with Powershell command Get-AzureStorageBlob in Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, storage, runbook

I'm trying to create a runbook in Azure that accesses a blob storage and list the contents. But I keep getting the following error:

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. HTTP Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

I checked the following:
Azure Portal -> Storage Account -> Networking -> Check Allow Access From (All Networks / Selected Networks)
It is set to all networks.

I checked the SAS. It's correct.

On the storage account and the container I set the Access Control to Storage Blob Data Reader and Sotrage Blob Data Owner to Managed Identity\Automation Account.

i created an Access Policy and set its rights to rdl, but I don't know how to call it from within my Powershell statement. I don't know whether it makes any difference.

Who can help me? I've about read all the articles on Internet but can't find the answer.

It's the statement Get-AzureStorageBlob that fails.

This is the code in the runbook:

```
$storage = "opslag" #name of storage account
$blobcontainer = "contener" #name of container
$sas = "****"

Write-Output $storage
Write-Output $container

$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage - 
SasToken $sas
Write-Output $context

$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $blobcontainer -Context 
$context
```

Comment: Does anyone have the answer?

Answer (score 0):

To test this in our local environment, we have created a storage account, automation account with PowerShell runbook

- We have enabled Managed identity for the automation account, given the [permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNA93.png)  `Storage blob data Reader, Storage Blob Data Owner` for the same managed identity.
- In the storage account, we have created an access policy with `read, delete, list` permissions to access the blob contents from PowerShell statements.

**Here is the PowerShell Script that we have run in the Automation account Runbook:**

- We have used the same [managed identity to authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/enable-managed-identity-for-automation#authenticate-access-with-system-assigned-managed-identity) to our azure account in the automation account.

```html
  Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process  # Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
    $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context # Connect to Azure with system-assigned managed identity
    $AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext  # set and store context
    
    Import-module -name Az.Storage
    
    $storage = "<strgName>"  #name of storage account
    $blobcontainer = "<containerName>"  #name of container
    $sas = "<SAStoken>"  # Generated SAS token for the container with allowing HTTP & HTTPS protocol.
    Write-Output $storage
    Write-Output $container
    $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage -SasToken $sas
    Write-Output $context
    $blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $blobcontainer -Context $context
    Write-Output $blobs
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]